# AMD Module Loading Error with Mustache using RequireJS

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, mustache

I am following the tuturoial here: http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/ and all I would like to do is use Mustache instead of underscore.js for my templating engine in a Backbone View. Everything is working as expected until I try to do the replacement  of Mustache. Firebug gives me this:

`Load timeout for modules: Mustache`

My Mustache wrapper (in `libs/mustache/mustache-wrap.js`) is like so:

```js
define(['libs/mustache/mustache'], function(){
  // Tell Require.js that this module returns a reference to Mustache
  return Mustache;
});
```

Here is the code for my Backbone View:

```js
// Protocol Detail View
define([
  'jQuery',
  'Underscore',
  'Backbone',
  'Mustache',
  'collections/protocols',
  'text!templates/protocol/protocoldetail.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, Mustache, protocolCollection, protocolDetailTemplate){

    var protocolDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: "#asset-detail",
        render: function( pid ){
            this.collection = new protocolCollection;
            this.collection.fetch();
            var p = this.collection.getByCid('c'+pid);
            var template = "{{name}}";
            htmlr = Mustache.to_html(template, p);
            $(this.el).html(htmlr);
            //var compiledTemplate = _.template( protocolDetailTemplate, { protocol: protocol });
            //$(this.el).html(compiledTemplate);

        },

        events: {
            "submit #asset-owner": "chown"
        },

        chown: function ( pid ){
            console.log("Protocol Detail View chown callback.")
        }
    });

    return new protocolDetailView;
});
```

My `main.js` file has the following config:

```js
require.config({
    paths: {
      jQuery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
      jQueryUI: '//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min',
      jstree: 'libs/jstree/jquery.jstree',
      Mustache: 'libs/mustache/mustache-wrap',
      Underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
      Backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you main.js file where you have all you're requires, make sure to add Mustache to the config, and don't worry about the wrapper and just try loading Mustache directly.

```
require.config({ 
    'paths': { 
        "underscore": "libs/underscore", 
        "backbone": "libs/backbone",
        "Mustache": "libs/mustache/mustache"
    }
});
```

That might help...

Also, here are some starter apps to help you out on your require, backbone journey.

https://github.com/jcreamer898/RequireJS-Backbone-Starter
https://github.com/david0178418/BackboneJS-AMD-Boilerplate
https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals
https://github.com/amdjs

Comment: Thanks @jcreamer898, but I already have that in my main.js. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: So, I guess that means you haven't figured it out yet eh?

Comment: Nope, which leads me to something I wish I had put in the questions which is how do I know if a module is AMD-safe or not?

Comment: You'll find code in it that looks like what you are trying to do... I.E. `define('moduleName', function(){ });` or take a look at the first few lines of https://github.com/amdjs/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js

Comment: You may or may not actually need to use the Mustach wrapper. I used handlebars for something recently and just had the `'Handlebars': 'libs/handlebars/handlebars'` in my require config, and that was it...

Comment: Since mustache isn't actually AMD, all you are really doing when you call the module is loading mustache and getting Mustache put into the global namespace.

Comment: Alright, I was able to get this working by just removing the wrapper and using it directly just like you suggested.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8270/discussion-between-randy-and-jcreamer898)

Answer (score 2):

Clone the repository from github:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/janl/mustache.js.git
```

Then, build the RequireJS specific version of the library:

```
$ rake requirejs
```

Use the resulting file 'requirejs.mustache.js' as your mustache library.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Twitter's mustache repository](https://github.com/twitter/mustache.js)!

Here is what worked for me (Ubuntu 12.04):

```
sudo apt-get install rake ruby-rspec
git clone git://github.com/twitter/mustache.js.git
cd mustache.js/
rake requirejs
```