# Loading mustache using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mustache

I would like to load and use mustache by requirejs.

Maybe this question has already asked:
[AMD Module Loading Error with Mustache using RequireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439261/amd-module-loading-error-with-mustache-using-requirejs)

Anyway I am trying to figure out how can I fix my code:

---

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
        underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-optamd3-min',
        mustache: "libs/mustache/mustache"
    }
});

require([
    'views/app'
    ], function(AppView){
        var app_view = new AppView;
 });
```

---

**app.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore', 
    'backbone',
    "mustache"
    ], function($, _, Backbone, Mustache) {
        console.log($, _, Backbone, Mustache); // <-- *** Mustache is null ***
        // ......
       }
);
```

---

As you can see in the comment on `app.js` file, `Mustache is null`...
Should I use another library of Mustache?
Here what I am using [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should just create in your mustache directory a new file mustache-wrap.js which looks like this:

```
 define(['libs/mustache/mustache'], function(Mustache){
    // Tell Require.js that this module returns a reference to Mustache
    return Mustache;
 });
```

and then your main will be:

```
  mustache: "libs/mustache/mustache-wrap"
```

Comment: @AntoJs The first line should read; `define(['libs/mustache/mustache'], function(Mustache){`

Answer (score 17):

Looks like Mustache [supports AMD modules](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/commit/33920ad674126483414b8e879c57558352a382ed) as of July '12. So it should now work out of the box with a loader such as require.js.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if `RequireJS` 2.1.0 was out at the time of posting this question (and the answers) but the preferred way of handling this now is using `shim` config element (more info [on project's docs page](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)).

Your main.js would become:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
        underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-optamd3-min',
        mustache: "libs/mustache/mustache"
    },
    shim: {
        'mustache': {
            exports: 'Mustache'
        }
    }
});
(...)
```

That's *effectively* the same as wrapper suggested @AntoJs, but without the boilerplate code.

...but then, since Mustache supports AMD there's no need to wrap/shim in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably also do in-line named define in the code that consumes mustache, or somewhere in "main.js" (saves the trouble of creating *-wrap file)

```
define('mustache', ['libs/mustache/mustache'], function(){
    // Tell Require.js that this module returns a reference to Mustache
    return Mustache; // from global
});
require(
    ['jquery','underscore','backbone','mustache']
    , function($, _, BB, Mustache){
        // use them
    }
)
```