# RequireJS not loading Mustache window object

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mustache

I'm implementing the search functionality described [here](https://github.com/slashdotdash/jekyll-lunr-js-search) for my Jekyll site but it needs six separate JavaScript files to work, so I'd like to use RequireJS to load all of these files as dependencies. Things are not working and the Error Console messages produce different results.

- Webkit says `Uncaught ReferenceError: Mustache is not defined`. The file that's sending out the message `jquery.lunr.search.js`, which is the last JS file listed as a dependency.
- Firefox and Opera return their respective versions of console errors for two separate files: `SecondLevelDomains.js` and `IPv6.js`.
- Seeking an IE browser.

RE: getting Mustache and RequireJS to work together, there are lots of answers to this on SO but none of them seem to work for me in this instance. The current implementation of the site I'm using can be seen [here](http://karem.kaidez.com/).

A more visual representation of the code:

RequireJS reference in the HTML:

`<script data-main="/js/config.js" src="/js/require.js" ></script>`

Site structure

```
index.html
js
 |__require.js
 |__config.js
 |__search.js
 |__vendor
   |__date.format.js
   |__jquery.js
   |__jquery.lunr.search.js
   |__lunr.min.js
   |__mustache.js
   |__URI.min.js
```

`config.js` looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: "/js",

  deps: ["search"],

  paths: {
    jquery: "vendor/jquery",
    lunr: "vendor/lunr.min",
    mustache: "vendor/mustache",
    dateFormat: "vendor/date.format",
    uri: "vendor/URI.min",
    LunrSearch: "vendor/jquery.lunr.search"
  },

  shim: { 
    jquery: {
      exports: 'jquery'
    },
    lunr: {
      exports: 'lunr'
    },
    'mustache': {
      exports: 'Mustache'
    },
    dateFormat: {
      exports: 'dateFormat'
    },
    uri: {
      deps: ['jquery'],
      exports: 'uri'
    },
    LunrSearch: {
      deps: ['jquery', 'mustache'],
      exports: 'LunrSearch'
    }
  }
});
```

And `search.js` (which should fire everything up) looks like this:

```
define("search", ["jquery", "lunr", "mustache", "uri", "dateFormat", "LunrSearch"],
  function($, lunr, mustache, dateFormat, uri, LunrSearch) {

    $('#search-query').lunrSearch({
      indexUrl: '/search.json', // URL of the `search.json` index data for your site
      results:  '#search-results', // jQuery selector for the search results container
      entries:  '.entries', // jQuery selector for the element to contain the results list, must be a child of the results element above.
      template: '#search-results-template'  // jQuery selector for the Mustache.js template
  });

});
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure Mustache needs a shim? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439261/amd-module-loading-error-with-mustache-using-requirejs

Comment: thefrontender: thanks for responding! Yes, I saw that answer,  I remove the shim and tested it..unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Any chance of looking at a test page or JSFiddle?

Comment: thefrontender: Appreciate the help!  Link is [here](http://karem.kaidez.com/). If you check the console messages, you'll see that Mustache object is not defined.